# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in an impossible place

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

A customer has managed to get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" where I don't understand how it can happen. I cannot repeat the error, it works every time for me. C# Mvc 5.2.4.0 Razor page.

Here is the elmah error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
>     object.
>     at ASP._Page_Views_SolidCore_SaveQuotation_cshtml.Execute() in [removed for 
>     brevity]\SaveQuotation.cshtml:line 105
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext 
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at 
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList 
>   1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>   at 
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList 
>   1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>   at 
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList > 1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>   at 
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(Controller
>   Context controllerContext, IList 1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.
>   b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

It's a little hard to read, but to summerise: Line 105 in a cshtml file:
[image: Capture of Webpage]
Line 105 of said cshtml file reads:

```
<h4>Quote @Model.QuoteNumber - @Model.QuotePrice</h4>
```

QuoteNumber and QuotePrice are strings, here's the model:

```
public class QuotationModel : DoorVaultLayoutModel
{
    public int QuoteID { get; set; }
    public string QuoteNumber { get; set; }
    public string QuotePrice { get; set; }
    public string AccountCode { get; set; }
    ...
    public bool LoggedIn => (UserTicket != null);
    public QuotationType QuotationType { get; set; }
}
```

So my problem here is I can't see how I can get a Object reference... error on a Model.string when the Model has already been tested with Model.LoggedIn, so the code can't get to line 105 unless Model is not null, and the other values on line 105 are nullable so this shouldn't be a problem.

I don't know if this is on POST or GET, the customer isn't being helpful, but I can't see why that would make a difference here, however the Action in both GET and POST have the very first line declaring a new model.

Stumped. Please help.

Comment: I wouldn't trust that line number info too much. It might be off (after all, that's cshtml, which gets converted to C#, which then is compiled to IL, which then compiled by JIT in assembly code), you might have different version of source code compared to what was deployed, and so on.

Comment: I don't see how; this page hasn't changed for a good few releases, we use managed release through Bamboo and Octopus, in 2 years I've never known line numbers not be right.

Comment: In 10 years I've seldom experienced line numbers to be *right*, even with correct debugging symbols right next to it, so that shows how experiences go. Seriously, it's quite unreliable, the main culprit being the JIT compiler inlining stuff and then not tracking line numbers accurately. Do *not* trust the line number or you'll drive yourself crazy. Assume any *other* line in the method can be the problem -- probably *around* line 105 somewhere, but not on it. If that doesn't help, you'll have to bite the bullet and get a crash dump so you can pinpoint the exact location.

Comment: Well you see yourself that model cannot be null, and nothing else can throw this exception on this line - so assume that line number is wrong, and explore other possibilities.

Comment: *I can't see how I can get a Object reference... error* - `string` is a reference type and can potentially be `null`, so yes it can potentially throw this error if one of your models is populated with a `null` string.

Comment: Jeroen, I thought elmah was the crash dump, what further information can be gathered and from where. I am assuming theres in;t going to be anything in the IIS logs and the event logs aren;t going to see it because it was caught and logged via Elmah. What else can I get?